# Matlab Portfolio Optimization: Calculating the IN-efficient frontier

Tags: matlab, portfolio

I have a question with regards to Portfolio Optimization in Matlab. Is there a way to plot and obtain the values in the **IN-efficent** frontier (the bottom locus of points that envelopes the feasible solutions as opposed to the efficient frontier which envelopes the top portion)?

```
if ~exist('quadprog')
msgbox('The Optimization Toolbox(TM) is required to run this example.','Product dependency')
return
end

returns      = [0.1 0.15 0.12];
STDs         = [0.2 0.25 0.18];
correlations = [ 1   0.3  0.4
                0.3   1   0.3
                0.4  0.3   1 ];

% Converting to correlation and STD to covariance matrix
covariances = corr2cov(STDs , correlations);

% Calculating and Plotting Efficient Frontier
portopt(returns , covariances , 20)

% random Portfolio Generation
weights = exprnd(1,1000,3);
total   =  sum(weights , 2);
total   =  total(:,ones(3,1));
weights =  weights./total;

[portRisk , portReturn] = portstats(returns , covariances , weights);

hold on
plot(portRisk , portReturn , '.r')
title('Mean-Variance Efficient Frontier and Random Portfolios')
hold off
```

Is there a way/command to obtain the return/risk/weight of the lower envelope of the feasible solution in the same way that the efficient frontier can be calculated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Did you every get this working?  I'm not sure if the link below will help, but I think it will get you very close to where you want to be.

http://www.mathworks.com/examples/finance/2059-portfolio-optimization-examples